# Nested documents in mongodb implementation, just like Reddit comments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my project, I would like to implement a comment section which consists of list of comments.

```
const myschema= mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    //other fields
    comments : [comment]
 },{collection : 'TABLE_NAME'} );


const comment= mongoose.Schema({
    _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,

    commentid: String, // id consists of uuid1()
    senderid: Number, //user's id
    body: String, // useful information
    parent: String,// parent id consists of uuid1()
    children: [] // I couldn't add children = [comment], it gives me an error, 
    //instead, I make it empty and will fill it when a comment comes
})
```

In the request tab, I will receive a JSON in the following format:

```
{
 "userid": "NUMBERID HERE",
 "comment": "COMMENT BODY",
 "parent" : "Comment's parent id"
}
```

I would like to add a comment which can be a child of another comment. How can I search and find the appropriate position?

If there are no parent in JSON body, I'm doing this:

```
// import comment somewhere at the beginning
.then(doc =>{

var newc= new comment();
newc.cid = uuidv1();
newc.sender = req.body.userid;
newc.body = req.body.comment;
newc.parent = "";
newc.children = "";
doc.comments.push(newc);

// save to DB
doc
.save()
.then(docres =>{
     res.status(200).json(docres);
})
.catch(err => {
     res.status(500).json({error: err});
})
}
```

I have no idea how to find a comment that resides in a deep level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.

The manually traversing the comments and inserting in the right place works. However, it only works up to some level. In my case, I can insert a comment below comment and save it. I can also insert a 3rd deep level comment and see the JSON dump of the object that I have inserted or even wrap it in an HTTP response object and send to the client. But the database does not save this update.

What I did is, after inserting the comment in the correct place I added this code before saving to the database.

```
  doc.markModified('comments'); // this is added
  doc.save().then(/*prepare response*/);
```

Somehow the MongoDB or mongoose or javascript interpreter knows the document has been changed and save the updated version. If the `markmodified` part is not specified, probably the compiler thinks that the object has not been modified and skips it.

Hopefully, this helps people who encounter this issue.
This is my implementation

```
        // find the document which comment is going to be inserted
        MyDOC.findOne({'id' : req.params.id})
        .exec()
        .then(doc =>{
            // if the comment has a parent, it should be inserted in nested
            if(req.body.parent != null && req.body.parent != undefined)
            {
                // find correct position and insert
                findComment(doc.comments, req.body);
                doc.markModified('comments');
                doc
                .save()
                .then(docres =>{
                    res.status(200).json(docres);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(500).json({error: err});
                })
            }
            else
            {
                //Add comment to the root level
                var comment= new Comment();
                comment.cid = uuidv1();
                comment.body = req.body.comment;
                comment.parent = "";

                doc.comments.push(comment);
                doc.markModified('comments');
                // save to DB
                doc
                .save()
                .then(docres =>{
                    res.status(200).json(docres);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(500).json({error: err});
                })
                }
        })


function findComment(comment, body)
{
    comment.forEach(element => {
        if(element.children.length != 0)
        {
            if(element.cid === body.parent)
            {
                // found, insert
                var comment= new Comment();

                comment.cid = uuidv1();
                comment.body = body.comment;
                comment.parent = body.parent;

                element.children.push(comment);
                return true;
            }

            if(findComment(element.children, body, usr))
                return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // this comment does not have children. If this comments id and the body's parent is equal, add it
            if(element.cid === body.parent)
            {
                // found, insert
                var comment= new Comment();

                comment.cid = uuidv1();
                comment.body = body.comment;
                comment.parent = body.parent;

                element.children.push(comment);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you face any performance issues with the above solution?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search for an array element or object property given an unspecified, arbitrarily-nested depth. It just isn't possible. You would need to instead handle this in the application layer. Denormalizing your data is fine in many cases, but arbitrary nesting depths isn't a recommended use case for data denormalization, especially since you can't index efficiently!

If you want a pure MongoDB solution, then you'll need a different document structure. I would recommend taking a look at the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/), particularly the section concerning an [array of ancestors](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-ancestors-array/), in order to properly model your data.

Comment: I have manually traverse the comments list(i.e, look for the element, if id's are not equal and if it has children -> go for the children do the same above).

I can add 1st and 2nd level comment to my database. However, I cannot save the third level. I can see that I have added correctly, but doc.save() function does not save the document somehow.